# Add #include's to the headers of a program using llvm clang

Tags: clang, llvm, header-files

I need to add headers to an already existing program by transforming it with LLVM and Clang.

I have used clang's rewriter to accomplish a similar thing in the changing function names and arguments, etc.

But the header files aren't present in clang's AST. I already know we need to use PPCallbacks (https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1PPCallbacks.html) but I am in dire need of some examples on how to make it work with the rewriter if at all possible.

Alternatively, adding a #include statement just before the first

```
using namespace <namespace>;
```

Also works. I would like to know an example of this as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you add `#include` directives in the genuine source file (the original `*.cc` or `*.cpp` file)? You don't need Clang for that (even if of course you could use sophisticated static analysis techniques, with Clang and/or LLVM, to determine *which* headers files to include). I mean, adding some preprocessor directive near the start of some source code is very simple (can be done with `sed`), the issue is to know *which* header file to include!

Comment: It's a part of my project. I am not allowed to manually alter the files. And I know exactly which header file to include!!

Comment: But you could alter *automatically* the files. And if you are not allowed to alter them, it is not a matter of adding a header file, but of adding declarations and definitions in a translation unit. The added stuff might then not even exist in any header file. You then should work *outside* of the preprocessor phase (so header files don't matter anymore)

Comment: It's just that the order of the header files matter. So I want to place the new header files after the rest of them are already in place. I figured out how to place it at the beginning.

Comment: No, you need and want to work on the *preprocessed* form of the code, and at that point header files don't exist anymore. Or you need to alter the physical source files, and then adding some `#include` line is quite simple (and can be done automatically, once you know which preprocessor directives should be added, and at what place).

Comment: I just need to statically get a #include <something.h> to appear after the rest of the #include's are done with. I am asking this on a very basic code transformation level. I am still new to clang.

Comment: As I have answered, you are confused about the role of the preprocessor.

Comment: don't comment your own question, but do edit it to improve it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of confusion in your question. You need to understand in details how the [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) works. Be aware that most of C++ compilation happens *after* the preprocessing phase (so most C++ static analyzers work after that phase).

<sup>In other words, the C++ specification (and also the C specification) defines first what is preprocessing, and then what is the syntax and the semantics of the preprocessed form.</sup>

In other words, when compiling  `foo.cc`  your compiler see the preprocessed form `foo.ii` that you could obtain with  `clang++ -C -E foo.cc > foo.ii`

<sup>In the 1980s the preprocessor `/lib/cpp` was a *separate program* forked by the compiler (and some temporary `foo.ii` was sitting on the disk and removed at end of compilation). Today, it is -for performance reasons- some initial processing done inside the compiler. But you could reason as if it was still separate.</sup>

Either you want to alter the Clang compiler, and it deals (like every other C++ compiler or C++ static analyzer) mostly with the *preprocessed* form. Then you don't want to add new `#include`-s, but you want to alter the flow of [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) given to the compiler (after preprocessing), and that is a different question: you then want to add some AST between existing AST elements (independently of any preprocessor directives).

Or you want to automatically change the C++ source code. The hard part is determining what you want to change and at what place. I suppose that you have used complex stuff to determine that a `#include <vector>` has to be inserted after line 34 of file `foo.cc`. Once you've got that information (and getting it is the hard thing), doing the insertion is pretty trivial. For example, you could read every C++ source line, and insert your line when you have read enough lines.

Comment: I have many source files that are different from each other. I am not going to compile anything (i.e. No 'clang++' command). I am running the ninja command to create an executable in bin/<name_of_executable>. I feed my file to this and I can see my re-written code as output (and the AST dump if i wish). It may help to know this is all done with the help of llvm build tools.

Comment: You need the preprocessing to be made, even if you are just analyzing (and not compiling) C++ code.